# Add a class attribute to body tag when a user is logged in

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, view

I want Joomla to add a class like "loggedIn" to body classes, when a user is logged in the page, in order to use this class and make specific css changes for logged in and non-logged in users.

I am using this jQuery to add a class to body but of course it missing the code to recognize if someone is logged in.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$( 'body' ).addClass( 'my-style' );
});
```

I also use the code below as php:

```
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$status = $user->guest;

if($status == 1){
//do user logged out stuff

}
else
{
//do user logged in stuff

}
?>
```

So in fact I want a combination of the above as jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addScriptDeclaration` to add some custom Javascript to the buffer, like so:

```
<?php

if (\Joomla\CMS\Factory::getUser()->guest === 0)
{
    \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration("
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            document.body.classList.add('loggedIn')
        });
    ");
}
```

Also note that I've used vanilla JS, as you don't need jQuery to add a class.

Comment: I added the code inside the Regular Labs Sourcerer  module, but I see this error on frontend: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Comment: @geoplous - I've updated the code, which should now work with Sourcerer

Comment: error fixed but I can not see the new class after login...

Comment: Do you see any errors on your browser console?

Comment: No I do not see any errors

Comment: Just tried with the latest version of Joomla and Sourcerer, using Firefox, and it works perfectly fine. I can see the `loggedIn` class on the `<body>` element.

Comment: joomla 4 or 3 ? on Joomla 3 without any customization does not work for me

Comment: I tested on Joomla 3

Comment: please see my settings:
https://paste.pics/c7ed3ebb99bf6bfa6d37275394d69ec7
https://paste.pics/03c2133d6e9193299b5ceb58282ec8f3

Comment: Is that custom module assigned to the page you're viewing?

Comment: yes, it is the named "Script" under the Login module

Comment: Ahhh. If you go to the `Options` tab in your module, enable the `Prepare Content` field. That should fix it.

Comment: you are the one, fixed and works fine, thank you